# How to make full width form items with Bootstrap for all items

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a responsive bootstrap form (v 2.3).

You can find the example under http://jsfiddle.net/uAKen/2/.

How can I make the "Text 2", "Text 3" and "Select 2" elements full width, so the look like "Text 1" and "Select 1".

I know, that the "problems" come from the input-append/input-prepend classes, but I want to have these styles.. For example:

```
<div class="input-append input-prepend span8">
    <span class="add-on">$</span>
    ...
    <span class="add-on">.00</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I think I have solved the problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/uAKen/3/

I had to add an additional wrapper areound the form fields.

```
<div class="input-wr">
...
</div>
```